# Selecting cells in a table using for-loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I need to obtain individual values from cells incrementally.

For example in a table called "T":

[image]

Can Matlab create a loop to yield the following?:

```
T(1,1)
T(1,2)
T(1,3)
T(1,4)
```

and so forth.

Comment: Note that a [table](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/matlab_prog/access-data-in-a-table.html) is something special in MATLAB, and is not the same as a [regular matrix](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the first parameter in MATLAB equals the row, the second the column. So following your picture you would want to extract a complete column. Then you have to loop over your first parameter and keep the 2nd constant.

So not sure if this is really what you want but:

```
for k = 1:size(T,1)
   T(k,1)
end
```

would write all elements in column 1 row after row. This is because `size(T,1)` returns the No. of rows in your Table. So by looping over all rows you return one column. Easier with the same result would be:

```
T(:,1)
```

which would return the whole first column.
If you don't want them to be displayed but to use them as entries for another variable use:

```
new_T = T(:,1);
```

The `;` makes sure that the command isn't displayed on the console. And the `new_T` would have all entries from column 1.

Another example:

```
new_T2 = T(1:500, 4);
```

This would result in the first 500 elements from column 4.

Hopefully this solves your question, if not please explain your question more detailed.

Comment: Sure about this? "First of all the first Parameter in matlab equals the column, the second the row". And this: "`T(:,1)` which would return the whole first row". I think you're mixing up rows and columns throughout the entire answer.

Comment: You are right. I mixed column and rows. ANd kept it wrong. Ty for the info. The code is right just my use of the words wasn't. Fixing it right now.

Comment: @RobertP. i think i fixed all cases where i swaped the names column and row. So now the wording is right as well (solution should have been working right all along). if you find another case where i mixed them up, pls feel free to edit the post.

Comment: @RobertP. i saw that you did minor changes like matlab to MATLAB and other formatting. Thx for that

Comment: I wasn't concerned about that part. I wanted to notify you that I changed your _code_ (something I only do very seldom), and give you the opportunity to change it back if you disagreed. =)